# Arduino: initialise custom object in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, arduino, arduino-ide

I've created 1 library with 2 classes. Class Wave and Class LEDLamps. In the second class constructor i'm trying to populate a array of first class objects without any luck.

Here are some parts of my real code.
h file:

```
static const int numberOfWaves = 20;

class Wave
{
public:
    Wave(int speed, int blockSize, int ledCount, int lightness,int startCount); // Constructor

private:

};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
class LEDLamps
{
public:
    LEDLamps(int8_t lampCount, int8_t dataPin, int8_t clockPin); //Constructor

private:
    Wave waveArray[numberOfWaves];
};
```

.cpp file

```
Wave::Wave(int speed, int blockSize, int ledCount, int lightness, int startCount) //Constructor
{ 
           // Doing some stuff...
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
LEDLamps::LEDLamps(int8_t lampCount, int8_t dataPin, int8_t clockPin) //Constructor
{ 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWaves; i++) {
        waveArray[i] = Wave(10,2,25,150,100);
    }
}
```

Error messages:

```
LEDLamps.cpp: In constructor 'LEDLamps::LEDLamps(int8_t, int8_t, int8_t)':
LEDLamps.cpp:66: error: no matching function for call to 'Wave::Wave()'
LEDLamps.cpp:14: note: candidates are: Wave::Wave(int, int, int, int, int)
LEDLamps.h:23: note:                 Wave::Wave(const Wave&)
```

What i understand from that error message the parameters are wrong but i'm sending 5 integer and constructor is defined to receive 5 integer? So i must be something else i'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you exactly what wrong, there is no `Wave::Wave()` method. You need a default constructor for the `Wave` class to be able to create an array of it. You might also want to create a copy-assignment operator if the `Wave` class contains non-trivial data.

The problem is that the array is constructed *before* the body of the `LEDLamps` constructor runs, so when inside the `LEDLamps` constructor body the array is fully constructed, and what you are doing is assignment (using the automatically generated copy-assignment operator).

---

Unfortunately the default Arduino C++ library it quite limited, at least when it comes to "standard" C++ features. There are [libraries that helps](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/blob/master/README.md), and if it's possible to use such a library you could have used an `std::vector` instead, which would allow you to construct the vector in the constructor initializer-list:

```
class LEDLamps
{
    ...
    std::vector<Wave> waveVector;
};

...

LedLamps::LEDLamps(...)
    : waveVector(numberOfWaves, Wave(10,2,25,150,100))
{
}
```